# Find record with exact three children

Tags: sql, join, activerecord

So we have `games` table which has many `participants`. Each participant has a `user_id` column. Now what we need is to find a game for a particular set of participants.

What I mean is having set of ids `(1,2,3)` we need to find a game in which participants are these exact three users, no more, no less.
I'm using active record and I tried something like:

`Game.joins(:participants).where("user_id in (?)", [1,2,3])`

But it returns all games which have at least one of the given users.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select g.games_id
from games g
group by g.games_id
having count(*) = sum(case when user_id in (1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) and
       count(*) = 3;  -- number of users in list
```

The first condition checks that all only the specified users are among the participants.  The second checks that all the users are included.